# Hooking into aframe-alongpath-component events and state

Tags: aframe, webvr

In the docs for the [aframe-alongpath-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-alongpath-component) it has a section on events and on state.

One of the states is "moveonpath" - The Entity currently moving along the path.

How would I hook into that so that whilst the entity is moving it plays a specific sound?

I'm also not clear from the docs how I could trigger the movement along the path to start in code from elsewhere. It appears to have an event you can listen to "movingstarted" but no play method I can call on the component.

The end goal I am trying to achieve is a rock being flung from a catapult.

When the catapult animation completes I want to trigger to rock the follow along a path for its trajectory and trigger a sound whilst moving and another when it reaches the end of the path (which will be in the ocean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking the state is quite simple:

```
element.is("state");
```

getting the 'ended' event is even simpler:

```
element.addEventListener("movingended", (e)=>{})
```

---

now add the event listener in the `init` function, and check the state in the tick function in a component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("movingended", (e) => {
      console.log("moving ended")
    })
  },
  tick: function() {
    console.log(this.el.is("moveonpath"));
  }
})
```

and attach the component:

```
<a-box foo></a-box>
```

check it out live [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d4mown7z/).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to suss the "movingended" event listener out before you answered but had no idea A-Frame entities had a local state that could be accessed via el.is("state").

I also discovered by looking into the components code that it does have a play method which I can access via element.components.alongpath.play()

The only problem I have now is that it autoplays on load instead of waiting to be played but I could fork the component and add an isPaused state which the tick listens too so it doesn't move until I set it to false.